# What are some libraries that do some of the follow image manipulation?

Tags: jquery, image-manipulation

I'm looking for some jQuery libraries or just JavaScript libraries that allows the user to move the images around and possibly have different layers, crop, and draggable resizing an image. I haven't quite found the library that does it all. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can combine multiple libraries, like, [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php), [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/).